# putw() function in C

Tags: c, gcc

Following program with putw is not writing the required data in the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("a.txt", "w");
   putw(25,fp);
   putw(325,fp);
   putw(425,fp);
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Program is compiled and executed like the following

```
gcc filename.c
./a.out
```

It is writing something in the file. Also if we read the integer using `getw()`, it is reading the value which is not available in the file. Even it is not the ASCII value.

When it is compiled with `gcc filename.c -std=c99`, it is showing implicit declaration warning error.

Is it required to link any library files to use putw/getw in c.

Comment: `putw()` would take the `integer` but store the corresponding ascii character for that integer.

Comment: you should use `fread` instead.

Comment: @Michi, Its written in the `man` page itself.. :D

Comment: @Haris What do you mean ?

Comment: @Michi, That suggestion is given in the `man page` of `putw()`

Comment: The warning is due to the fact that, although `putw` is defined (extern) in `stdio.h`, it's defined only under certain conditions. So, you don't really have an declaration for the function present when you compile. Second, why are you saying you aren't getting expected results? In your test program shown, reopen the file, and do three `getw` calls and see if you get 25, 325, and 425 back. When I tried it, it worked fine.

Comment: And from the manual page for `putw`: *`putw(w, stream)` writes the word `w` (that is, an `int`) to `stream`.  It is provided for compatibility  with  SVr4, but we recommend you use `fwrite(3)` instead.*

Answer (score 1):

There is no function called `putw` in standard C, which is why you get compiler warnings. You probably meant to use `putwc` in `wchar.h`.

Comment: doing a simple `man putw()` gives the info that its there in `stdio.h`

Comment: @Haris `putw` is a pre-ANSI function carried over from AT&T UNIX

Comment: @Haris What kind of ancient man page are you reading? [man putw](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getw.3.html). It is not C standard nor Posix standard. And it doesn't really matter, since Unix man pages don't dictate the C standard, and searching for putw in the C standard gives zero hits.

Comment: @Lundin, I read *...It's provided for compatibility with SVr4...*. And i thought it could be used.

Answer (score 1):

`putw` is an ancient function that exists on some platforms.  Use `fwrite` and `fread` instead.  You should also check the return value from `putw`.  It may be telling you why it is failing.